# How to assign new value to a variable using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
def foo(var, new_value):
    var = new_value

x = 1
multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(x,2))
p.start()
p.join()
print(x)
```

I would expect the output of the `print(x)` is 2, but in fact I got 1. How could I assign new values to an existing variable?

Comment: Your `foo()` function doesn't change `x`, because `x` is fully evaluated before being passed to the function. `var` receives the value of `x` in `var`. You then change `var` to a different value. `var` is a local variable, so it goes away when `foo()` ends.

Comment: Adding to @kindall: The important part here is that this has nothing to do with `multiprocessing`; this wouldn't work if you just did `foo(x, 2)` with no `multiprocessing` involved at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [multiprocessing shared values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects);

```
import multiprocessing
import ctypes

def foo(var, new_value):
    var.value = new_value

x = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_int, 1)
print(x.value)
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(x,2))
p.start()
p.join()
print(x.value)
```

Comment: Note that this is changing two things: 1. It uses shared memory so `multiprocessing` can transfer data from child to a location where the parent can see it. 2. It changes a rebinding of `var` in `foo` to an attribute assignment; rebinding can never change the caller's version of an argument, but modifying an attribute will change the caller's value. #2 isn't specific to `multiprocessing`; it's a general rule of Python.